# How to determine WebRTC dataChannel.send is delivered?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to write a chat application using WebRTC and I can send the messages over the dataChannel using a code like bellow one:

```
const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

const dataChannel =
  peerConnection.createDataChannel("myLabel", dataChannelOptions);

dataChannel.onerror = (error) => {
  console.log("Data Channel Error:", error);
};

dataChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log("Got Data Channel Message:", event.data);
};

dataChannel.onopen = () => {
  dataChannel.send("Hello World!");
};

dataChannel.onclose = () => {
  console.log("The Data Channel is Closed");
};
```

with `dataChannel.send()` I can send data over the channel correctly. but I am wondering to know, is there any way to determine that the sent message is delivered to another side or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simplest answer is: send a reply.

But you may not need to, if you use an [ordered](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-datachannel-ordered), [reliable](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dfn-data-transport) datachannel (which is the default).

#### An ordered reliable datachannel

With one of these, you determine a message was *sent*, by waiting for the [bufferedAmount](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-datachannel-bufferedamount) to go down:

```js
const pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();
const channel = pc1.createDataChannel("chat");

chat.onkeypress = async e => {
  if (e.keyCode != 13) return;

  const before = channel.bufferedAmount;
  channel.send(chat.value);

  const after = channel.bufferedAmount;
  console.log(`Queued ${after - before} bytes`);

  channel.bufferedAmountLowThreshold = before; // set floor trigger and wait
  await new Promise(r => channel.addEventListener("bufferedamountlow", r));

  console.log(`Sent ${after - channel.bufferedAmount} bytes`);
  chat.value = "";
};

pc2.ondatachannel = e => e.channel.onmessage = e => console.log(`> ${e.data}`);
pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => console.log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = async e => {
  await pc1.setLocalDescription(await pc1.createOffer());
  await pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription);
  await pc2.setLocalDescription(await pc2.createAnswer());
  await pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription);
}
```

```html
Chat: <input id="chat"><br>
```

Since the channel is *reliable*, it won't give up sending this message until it's been received.

Since the channel is *ordered*, it won't send a second message before this message has been received.

This lets you send a bunch of messages in a row without waiting on a reply. As long as the `bufferedAmount` keeps goes down, you know it's being sent and received.

In short, to determine a message was received, send a second message, or have the other side send a reply.

## An unreliable datachannel

If you're using an [unreliable](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dfn-data-transport) datachannel, then sending a reply is the only way. But since there's no guarantee the reply will make it back, this may produce false negatives, causing duplicate messages on the receiving end.

## Unreliable one way, reliable the other

Using the [negotiated](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcdatachannelinit-negotiated) constructor argument, it's possible to create a datachannel that's unreliable in one direction, yet reliable in the other. This can be used to solve the unreliable reply, to avoid duplicate messages on the receiving (`pc2`) end.

```
dc1 = pc1.createDataChannel("chat", {negotiated: true, id: 0, maxRetransmits: 0});
dc2 = pc2.createDataChannel("chat", {negotiated: true, id: 0});
```

Comment: Note it overwrites `bufferedAmountLowThreshold` though. Needs a bit more work before it will work with multiple messages in an actual clog. But it illustrates the point I hope.